A container is not being created in docker with minicube
I have such a problem that when writing the minicube start command, I start downloading and at the same time it takes a very long time, then it switches to qemu.The logs are listed below.
minikube start
  minikube v1.33.1 на Fedora 39
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: qemu2, none, ssh
  Using Docker driver with root privileges
❗  For an improved experience it's recommended to use Docker Engine instead of Docker Desktop.
Docker Engine installation instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/#server
  Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
  Pulling base image v0.0.44 ...
  Скачивается Kubernetes v1.30.0 ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v18-v1...:  342.90 MiB / 342.90 MiB  100.00% 5.22 Mi
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
❗  Startup with docker driver failed, trying with alternate driver qemu2: Failed to start host: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
  Removing /home/network_fox/.minikube/machines/minikube ...
  Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
  Automatically selected the builtin network
❗  You are using the QEMU driver without a dedicated network, which doesn't support `minikube service` & `minikube tunnel` commands.
  Downloading VM boot image ...
    > minikube-v1.33.1-amd64.iso....:  65 B / 65 B [---------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
    > minikube-v1.33.1-amd64.iso:  314.16 MiB / 314.16 MiB  100.00% 2.59 MiB p/
  Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
  Creating qemu2 VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...\ 

And when I register the driver, the following logs pop up
minikube start --driver=docker
  minikube v1.33.1 на Fedora 39
✨  Используется драйвер docker на основе конфига пользователя
  Using Docker driver with root privileges
❗  For an improved experience it's recommended to use Docker Engine instead of Docker Desktop.
Docker Engine installation instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/#server
  Starting "minikube" primary control-plane node in "minikube" cluster
  Pulling base image v0.0.44 ...
  Creating docker container (CPUs=4, Memory=2200MB) ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
  Creating docker container (CPUs=4, Memory=2200MB) ...
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

❌  Exiting due to DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT: Failed to start host: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  Предложение: Try 'minikube delete', and disable any conflicting VPN or firewall software
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7072

And it's written to me that I may have a VPN enabled, but I checked everything and I have no VPN connected. Please help me solve this problem. I just want everything to run in Docker. And I use Fedora 39, maybe this info will help in some way
I updated the docker desktop and I jump on this link https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7072,like the terminal said to me, i tried everything. Please help me with this issue.

Incase if you are behind proxy and vpn , please set this :
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy hostname:port>
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://<proxy hostname:port>
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.96.0.0/12,192.168.59.0/24,192.168.49.0/24,192.168.39.0/24

for more information:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/
